# Error when building the substrate node on mac M1: incorrect value `...` for codegen option `split-debuginfo

Tags: substrate-node-template, build

While following the installation tutorial available at: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/installation/

I ended up with cloning the node-template repository and running the build command as shown below which thrown an codegen error.

I tried avoiding this error by providing the misconfigured flag in the release profile section of the Cargo.toml config without any luck. Any ideas?

```
Marco-Polo :: workspace/substrate/substrate-node-template ‹fbe735e*› % cargo build --release                     
   Compiling libc v0.2.125
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.37
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.3
   Compiling syn v1.0.92
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling serde v1.0.137
   Compiling serde_derive v1.0.137
   Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0
error: incorrect value `...` for codegen option `split-debuginfo` - one of supported split-debuginfo modes (`off`, `packed`, or `unpacked`) was expected

error: could not compile `unicode-xid` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: could not compile `version_check` due to previous error
error: could not compile `cfg-if` due to previous error
error: could not compile `autocfg` due to previous error
error: could not compile `syn` due to previous error
error: could not compile `serde_derive` due to previous error
error: could not compile `libc` due to previous error
error: could not compile `memchr` due to previous error
error: could not compile `serde` due to previous error
error: could not compile `proc-macro2` due to previous error
```

I am trying to build this under osx with an m1 pro cpu and the following software packages:

```
Marco-Polo :: workspace/substrate/substrate-node-template ‹main*› % gcc -v                                  
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Marco-Polo :: workspace/substrate/substrate-node-template ‹main*› % g++ -v                                       
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Marco-Polo :: workspace/substrate/substrate-node-template ‹main*› % make -v                                      
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

Marco-Polo :: workspace/substrate/substrate-node-template ‹main*› % uname -a                                     
Darwin Marco-Polo.local 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: Fri Mar 18 00:46:32 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.101.4~15/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64

Marco-Polo :: workspace/substrate/substrate-node-template ‹main*› % rustup +nightly show                         
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/lucio/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustc 1.62.0-nightly (4c60a0ea5 2022-05-04)
```

Update1: regarding opening a github issue, I have initially tried doing so but it seems the issue page redirects me to stackexchange:

```
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/new/choose
```

Support & Troubleshooting with the Substrate Stack Exchange Community
For general problems with Substrate or related technologies, please search here first for solutions, by keyword and tags. If you discover no solution, please then ask and questions in our community! We highly encourage everyone also share their understanding by answering questions for others.

Update2:

Regarding `rustup show` this is the output I get:

```
:: ~ % rustup show                                                                                     
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/lucio/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.62.0-nightly (4c60a0ea5 2022-05-04)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this probably should be posted as an issue in Substrate repo.

Comment: @pepyakin I have tried posting it in the node-template repo and it redirects me to stackexchange, check my update.

Comment: Hey Lucian and sorry for this bad experience. This looks as a bug to me, that's why I figured it would be better off as an issue.

Comment: do you have any environment variables defined? How did you install Rust? Have you tried overriding the rust toolchain? what's the output of just `rustp show`, without +nightly?

Comment: No worries, I think sorting out this issue will be beneficial for everyone starting out with substrate on mac silicon. I have updated my post with the `rustup show` output.

On the same note, I don't have any rust specific env vars, the installation was done following the guide on https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/installation/

Comment: Sure, agreed. The thing is that I write this text from an M1 machine as well and the project builds well for me without any problem, hence the questions and thinking that it's a bug. I am not sure what is happening. Have you tried running `cargo clean`? Maybe reinstalling the parts/whole of the toolchain helps?

Comment: Cleaning the project didn't help, I have also tried re-installing the toolchain without luck, is there a place in github I could open up an issue? I believe this thing deserves an indepth investigation.

Comment: Can you check if the same happens when you are building https://github.com/paritytech/substrate ? If so, I'd leave it there.

Comment: I've found the issue, I had a previous installation of fleet lying around: https://github.com/dimensionhq/fleet it seems it was polluting the dependencies list somehow. Removed that and everything works as expected. Thanks!